# Затемнить экран по нажатию на 'FloatingActionButton'

Tags: android

Нужно затемнить и заблокировать все элементы на экране по нажатию на `floatingActionButton`, при этом добавить две новые кнопки.
[image: начальное состояние]

[image: Конечное состояние]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Как вариант можно добавить поверх затемненный слой, на котором есть твои кнопки.

Comment: Через `setContentView` что-ли другую xml разметку загрузить? Если так то не подходит, мне нужно именно затемнить текущее содержимое, а поверх 2 кнопки.

Comment: Попробуйте эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)
Надеюсь, поможет вам...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге сам разобрался. В основной разметке разместил две кнопки в контейнере `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/linGroupButtonAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroud">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/box"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabAddBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/thing"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabAddThing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

вот код основной кнопки `FloatingActionButton`

```
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewGroup linGroupButtonAdd = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linGroupButtonAdd);
            linGroupButtonAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_fab);
            View viewAddThing = (View) findViewById(R.id.fabAddThing);
            viewAddThing.startAnimation(anim);
            viewAddThing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Добавить вещь", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            View viewAddBox = (View) findViewById(R.id.fabAddBox);
            viewAddBox.startAnimation(anim);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

Цвет для затемнения:

```
    <color name="colorBackgroud">#ccffffff</color>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как собственно происходит затемнение.

Comment: Основная кнопка `FloatingActionButton` размещена в разметке app_bar_main. После ее нажатия, сама кнопка скрывается, одновременно делается видимым контейнер `FrameLayout` c двумя кнопками `FloatingActionButton`. Атрибуту backgroud, данного контейнера, присваивается белый цвет с альфа каналом `#ccffffff`, а так как контейнер находится поверх контейнера `drawer_layout`, то он его просто затемняет. В итоге получается затемненный `drawer_layout` и две кнопки, которые размещены на `FrameLayout`.